# Scheduling using the Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, design-patterns, task-parallel-library

I have to process around 200.000 objects (in a desktop application) and each object takes around 20 ms to process. In order to speed this up I want to do it concurrently.

For testing I just put each object in a separate task, but due to the small size of the job this only yields a tiny speed improvement. So my first question is:

Is there a clever (but not too complicated) way to find a optimal batch size for these objects? I guess I could to some local testing on whether it is fastest to group them together in batches of 10, 20 or 100 objects, but this seems a bit suboptimal.

Secondly (and more important): Most of the objects should just be processed whenever they get some CPU time. However, the user will always be looking at 10-20 objects. I want to always be able to put the objects the user is looking on in the front of the queue in order to deliver a smooth user experience. The user might navigate around all the time so I feel it is important to always be able to quickly reschedule the order. (20 ms * 20 should be able to be processed in around 0.4 seconds).

Can someone help me with a good design patten for processing these objects?

Comment: What kind of processing are you talking about? Is it CPU-bound?

Comment: You might need to define _optimal_ wrt batch size. Most simply: divide item count by number of cores/processors. Total throughput is an obvious factor but also important is responsiveness to the user; if batch size is too large then if the user wants to see items that happen to be in a batch, the relevant thread could take too long to deliver those items (unless the thread delivers processed items in smaller groups). Your threads could support rescheduling so that, when required, items X..Y must move to the head of the queue.

Comment: `Queue<T>` is the obvious collection class but it doesn't support rescheduling (unless you use an extension method like `SkipWhile`). Alternatively, use `List<T>` which has methods `AddRange`, `RemoveRange`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Parallel.ForEach or Parallel.For if the objects are in a collection. Due to your user responsiveness requirements Parallel.For would be a better choice.

Unfortunately, there's no substitute for measuring performance and tweaking your strategy based on the results.

Comment: Could you explain why do you think that Parallel.For would be better?

Comment: The OP's requirement was that any objects a user is viewing take priority for processing. Assuming the user is looking at contiguous items in the container, Parallel.For can be run on that slice of items.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process the items in parallel and you don't care about the order, just use `Parallel.ForEach()` (call it from a background thread so that you don't block the UI thread).

But if you want to implement that dynamic priority change, that's going to be more complicated.

One way would be to have an object, let's call it `Job`, that would represent single action that has to be executed. Then you would have a method that processes a queue of jobs, but executing those with high priority if there are any. Something like:

```
Queue<Job> jobs;
IEnumerable<Job> priorityJobs;

void ProcessJobs()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Job job = null;

        lock (jobs)
        {
            job = priorityJobs.FirstOrDefault(j => j.NotYetStarted);

            if (job == null)
            {
                do
                {
                    if (jobs.Count == 0)
                        return;

                    job = jobs.Dequeue();
                } while (job.NotYetStarted);
            }

            job.NotYetStarted = false;
        }

        job.Execute();
    }
}
```

You would then start threads to execute `ProcessJobs()` in parallel, for example:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, Environment.ProcessorCount)
    .Select(_ => Task.Run(() => ProcessJobs()));
```